# Am I able to run commands from flutter?

Tags: flutter

What I'm trying to do is run a program from my Windows/Mac flutter applications. Is there something similar to Process in java or the exec package in Go for Dart/Flutter?

The googling I have done has only led to descriptions of how to use the flutter command, and that is NOT what I am looking for.

Comment: What do you get while using `flutter` command ?

Comment: I'm not having issues with the flutter command, I'm trying to execute programs from my app.

Comment: Do you have building issue? I am not getting the question

Comment: I am trying to execute commands in my app. I have an exe that I want to run when a user clicks a button, and I am trying to figure out how to run it. In Go, you can use exec.Command, and then the Start method on the returned struct. In C you can use the system function. How do I do the same in dart with flutter?

Answer (score 1):

In dart:io,
Process.run and Process.start, depending on the purpose of your program.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-io/dart-io-library.html